# want to use overflow for the contents in day of asp.net calendar control

Tags: asp.net, calendar, controls

I want to use overflow for the contents in day of asp.net calendar control.
I am trying

```
e.Cell.Style["height"] = "80px";
e.Cell.Style["overflow"] = "auto";
```

in a dayrender event of asp.net calendar control.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to assign the *style* attribute programatically. i.e.

```
e.Cell.Attributes.Add("style", "height: 80px; overflow: auto;");
```

Otherwise, take a look at the CSS classes generated by the control:

```
.ajax__calendar_container {height: 80px; overflow: auto;}
```

All the classes are documented at the bottom of this page:

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/Calendar/Calendar.aspx

Good Luck,

Marko